# Conditionally formatting a column with mutate and regex in R

Tags: r, regex, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm brand new in R and programming in general. I have a column containing a list of dates. Some are in the "01 January 2020" format, some have only month and year (ie "January 2020" only). I want to mutate them to a new field where I add a 01 in front of all the dates that are in the month year format, and then I will use lubridate to process it into dates

This is what I've tried. I'm trying to extract the first character of the Date column. If it is an upper case letter, then I will append "01" to it. I am using the tinyverse package including dplyr

```
df %>% mutate(new_date = ifelse(str_sub(Date, start = 1, end = 1)== "[:upper:]"), paste('01', Date, sep = ' '), new_date = Date)
```

I'm getting the error message "no is missing", but I thought I have included `new_date = Date` to keep the current formatting.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Thank you so much. It appears to be working if I put specific letters in the conditional to match, but doesn't work with the regex "[:upper:]". Is the formatting correct for the regex expression?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in many ways.

`base R` using lookahead and backreference:

```
sub("(^)(?=[A-Za-z]+)", "\\101 ", date, perl = TRUE)
[1] "01 January 2020"  "01 January 2020"  "12 February 1999" "01 March 2033"
```

`base R` using only backreference:

```
sub("(^[A-Za-z]+)", "01 \\1", date, perl = TRUE)
```

`dplyr` and `stringr` using the same logic:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

data.frame(date) %>%
  mutate(date = str_replace(date, "(^)(?=[A-Za-z]+)", "\\101 "))
```

If you do insist on using `ifelse`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

data.frame(date) %>% 
  mutate(date = ifelse(str_detect(date, "^[:upper:]"),
                       sub("^", "01 ", date),
                       date))
```

Data:

```
date <- c("01 January 2020","January 2020", "12 February 1999", "March 2033")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a non-regex option where we convert to `Date` class and `format` it

```
library(parsedate)
format(parse_date(date), '%d %B %Y')
[1] "01 January 2020"  "01 January 2020"  "12 February 1999" "01 March 2033"
```

#### data

```
date <- c("01 January 2020","January 2020", "12 February 1999", "March 2033")
```